# Start a transaction around the spring RepositoryEntityController

Tags: spring, transactions, aop, spring-data-rest, cglib

I use aop to start a transaction around the Spring data rest controller : org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController

I use the @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY) to enable AOP

this is my AOP config :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="restRepositoryTx"
            expression="execution(* org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor id="txManager" advice-ref="txAdvice"
            pointcut-ref="restRepositoryTx" order="20" />
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="postCollectionResource*" propagation="REQUIRED"
                rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="putItemResource*" propagation="REQUIRED"
                rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="patchItemResource*" propagation="REQUIRED"
                rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="deleteItemResource*" propagation="REQUIRED"
                rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />

            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

</beans>
```

But i'v got this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryEntityController' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/mjarrai/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.4.4.RELEASE/41c0fad87f74df36b3b4167f699523a0d505acd0/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.4.4.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.salepower.refdata.ReferenceDataServicesApplication.main(ReferenceDataServicesApplication.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:468)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:328)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:445)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:433)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:338)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:203)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:409)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84412b04 cannot access its superclass org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Please, How can i fix this ?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I'm using Spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a conflict between Spring DevTools ClassLoader and CGLIB. I'v just removed DevTools dependencies from my build.gradle file and every things works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

i log the spring date rest request by this way 
`@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.*Controller.*(..))")`

compile false and throw the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryEntityController' defined in URL [jar:file:/F:/jdk8Repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.5.3.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ssxt.groundwatercollect.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:470) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:55) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:203) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:413) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7df1465 cannot access its superclass org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
,
```

after i comment the dependency of spring-boot-devtools (s.b version 1.4.1.RELEASE) in pom.xml, compile pass.